# How to Implement Float Switch On/Off LEDs

Tags: led, switches, circuit-design

I've previously built this circuit to control a submersible pump with a PIR sensor:

[image]

I'm now going to add a float switch to the circuit to prevent the pump running if the water level gets too low. I would like to also include a green LED when the switch is on (sufficient water level) and a red LED when its off (low water level).

[image]

The circuit would therefore look like this with the inclusion of a red LED, however I can't think how to implement the red LED to be on when the switch is off and then to turn off when the switch is on (the inverse of the green LED's behaviour). Any pointers would be appreciated.

Note: R1 is meant to be 47k and a 1N4004 diode is across the motor

Comment: Does the float switch have both an NO and an NC contact by chance? You could add a relay in to give you that functionality, then it is pretty simple, the float operates the relay, use the NO side for the Green LED and the NC side for the Red LED...

Comment: It can be either NO or NC but not both unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a very simple modification that might be acceptable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqD51C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is closed, \$Q_1\$ is off and the red LED is also off. When the switch is open, \$Q_1\$ receives base drive via the green LED and \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$, sufficient to turn on the red LED. The green LED current will be cut down by a factor of about 20 (about \$1\:\textrm{mA}\$), so it won't be nearly so visible. There may also be some "leakage" into your pump/PIR circuit via \$R_3\$, but I don't think that will cause you trouble. You might want to lower \$R_1\$'s value, just in case. So this may, or may not, be acceptable in your circumstance. You'll have to decide. But it's easy to understand and implement.

---

Just for completeness, the "inverter" circuit that I believe was suggested might look like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiU3a6.png)</sup>

But the price paid here is that the red LED current either goes through the red LED or else it goes through \$Q_1\$. But the current is always present. So you pay an added price in current draw. That may also be acceptable, though.

Comment: Seems like a weak pull down is needed tho

Comment: @jonk is there a way to prevent or further limit the leakage via R3? Also how do I go about selecting a suitable BJT for this application (I have some experience selecting MOSFETs but have yet to use BJTs)?

Comment: @Seano Any PNP would do the job. The switch is carrying the motor current. When open, the PNP only sees very low current needed for the red LED. So any junkbox thing would do it, likely. I don't think the leakage will be a problem. But you should test it and see. The motor will NOT operate through \$R_3\$, that's for sure. But it's worth seeing what the PIR does to make sure. You could double the \$R_3\$ value to lower it still further without changing behavior to lower the leakage still further if that turns out important. Otherwise, it's a topology change.

Comment: @seano just a thought, but you should be careful using your float switch like that. In the instance that you are close to its switching point it is quite likely to bounce between on and off. Your pump is also reasonably high powered, so you're putting a decent current through a bouncing switch. This circuit will be fine in the lab, but in the field I would have the float acting as a low power switch with hysteresis.

Comment: To clarify, the hysteresis would be mechanical. You could also use a circuit that would latch off until reset, which is probably cleaner given the solution @jonk has given.

Comment: @awjlogan you are indeed correct about that. Unfortunately I got to witness it in practice as I had everything up and running before you commented. Would you mind going into a bit more detail on how I would go about applying this mechanical hysteresis and adding the latch off circuit? Thank you!

Comment: @Seano Of course! Mechanical hysteresis would be at the switch level itself, either you can make it yourself or a get a latching switch - it's a little limited. An electronic solution will be easier. I'll try and get round to it this afternoon :)

Comment: @Seano Added an answer, hopefully helpful. You can do it with discretes as well, but better to use an IC.

Answer (score 1):

Well, can't you just use a complementary NOT gate near the green led to power the red one?

[image: NOT gate example electronics-tutorials.ws]

([Source image](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/log47.gif) from [this webpage](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_4.html))

Comment: Applying that to my circuit would the resistor coming from A be in parallel to my green LED? @UtkarshBajpai

Comment: Yes, A would be in parallel, to the green LED.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the comments from jonk's answer, there is a problem in using the float switch to directly connect to the battery. When the water level approaches the switch set point, the switch will bounce indeterminately between on and off. This is a common problem when one has an on/off threshold for a slowly varying\$^1\$ analog signal, and can be addressed with [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis). This means that the on and off points are different, and the output will latch to on/off until the signal changes enough to reach the other set point.

In this system, the pump draws a fairly high amount of power, which you do not want pulsing on and off rapidly. It's usually best to have low power switches. Low power switches are usually cheaper, smaller, and there's often more choice.

A potential solution is shown in the schematic below. You can use a [4001 quad NOR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/schs015c/schs015c.pdf) IC, which will run directly from the 12 V supply you have (I haven't included decoupling etc) and as it's CMOS draws very little current. CMOS logic cannot drive much current (about 3 mA with a 12 V supply), so there's a small MOSFET to drive the red LED. The resistor values are fairly arbitrary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVkZK7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The main feature is the use an [SR (set/reset) latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) to hold the state of the float switch until actively reset using the other button; this provides the hysteresis. When the float switch pulls one input of NOR2 LOW, the output of NOR2 goes HIGH, and is then fed back to NOR1. NOR1's inputs are both now HIGH, and so it's output is LOW. The red LED will be on when the output of NOR2 is high (which is what you want). The system is now latched in this state until the opposite process with the Reset switch. The reset switch can either be manual, or you could (for example) have another float switch higher up in the tank so when the water reaches this point, the system will run again. Anything that will pull that input LOW in response to a higher water level is fine.

The other NOR gates generate the correct outputs given the system state: the pump is only on when the PIR output is HIGH, and the output from the latch is LOW.

\$^1\$ "Slowly changing" is relative to the speed of the switching element. A high speed comparator, for example, could switch in one nanosecond and so a slow signal in that application could be MHz in frequency. A mechanical switch may switch in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer @awjlogan. Just confirming, would a FQP30N06L mosfet work for M2 in your design? I believe it would be appropriate but confirmation would be great...Had to buy a bunch of them when I bought for M1 so would be ideal

Comment: No problem @Seano - your FQP30N06L will work, hugely overkill but if you have them to hand, why not :)

Comment: so I'm finally getting around to building this and have one final question. If I were to use a normally closed switch for the Reset (upside down float switch so that it will open once the water level is at its limit) and use a PNP BJT to invert its signal for NAND1, how would I actually go about fitting the BJT into the circuit for this funcitonality? @awjlogan

Comment: @Seano No need, just swap the position of R2 and Reset and that will do the same thing. When the switch is closed, the input will be HIGH and when it opens to reset, the input will be pulled LOW.

Comment: NAND4 should actually be a NOR gate right?

Comment: @Seano Nope - it needs to be a NAND. You only want the pump to run if the PIR output is HIGH (note the NAND gate used as an inverter) AND the float switch hasn't been closed. If it were a NOR gate, the PIR would trigger the pump regardless of the output from the switch. Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry I still can't quite wrap my head around this one. When the PIR output is high (NAND3 output is LOW) AND the float switch hasn't been closed (NAND2 output is LOW), both NAND4s inputs are LOW and so its output is HIGH. However, when the output of the PIR is low (NAND3 output is high) and the switch still hasn't been closed (NAND2 output is LOW), NAND4s inputs are now LOW and HIGH, which still gives a HIGH output. The only case where the pump won't run (NAND4 ouput is LOW) is when the PIR output is low (NAND3 output is HIGH) and the float switch is closed (NAND2 output is HIGH)

Comment: @Seano - I think my solution is wrong, and you were originally correct that NAND4 should be a NOR. I'll correct the schematic later on, good catch, and sorry for not thinking clearly through it.

Comment: thanks for your continued help! One more hurdle though - the PIRs output high is 3.5V but the NOR gate requires an input high min of 11V. Any suggestions on how to do this? I have very limited space left on my board so a solution that uses a 3pin solution would be ideal

Comment: @Seano You'll need a couple of resistors and a transistor to make a common emitter amplifier (just search). The CE amp is inverting, so just replace NOR3 with it. Hopefully that will fit!